Are US state political parties required to nominate the most popular candidates in their local primaries/caucases?
Do US state political parties have the freedom to arbitrarily decide which candidate ends up the nominee? Does that restriction/freedom hold at the national party level as well?

Could you give a specific example of the type of election you're thinking of? Elections can be for positions ranging from local government bodies (municipalities, counties) to state government, to the national level: at the local and to a lesser degree state levels, it is common for elections in the United States to be non-partisan without a party nomination process playing any official role.

I'm pretty sure that the answer you are looking for is that U.S. political parties have no control over who their nominee is as that is determined in the primary/caucus process.
